# How to start a Proxmox VM on Windows w/ Qemu

Tags: windows, qemu, proxmox

I'm trying to start a Proxmox VM using the qcow2 image on Windows using Qemu, however I can't figure out the correct parameters to start the machine.

Based on my settings in the Proxmox Web UI:

[image: Serrver settings screenshot taken from Proxmox Web UI]

I tried to run this CLI snippet:

```
PS > .\qemu-system-x86_64.exe -bios ./share/OVMF.fd -hda ./image/vm-103-disk-0.qcow2 -hdb ./image/vm-103-disk-1.qcow2 -machine type=q35
```

However, I'm stuck on a black screen:

[image]

Comment: On the Proxmox VE, you can figure out the exact command it uses to run the VM: 
`qm showcmd <vmid>`. You can then adapt this command to your environment.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov If you wrote it as an answer, I'd have chosen it as the solution! I've been searching for exactly that and now it works! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Proxmox VE, you can figure out the exact command it uses to run the VM:

```
qm showcmd <vmid>
```

(see [the manual page](https://pve.proxmox.com/pve-docs/qm.1.html))

You can then adapt this command to your environment. Things which likely need to be changed:

- The storage back-end configuration
- The networking settings
- In Windows, all sockets have to be replaced with TCP listeners, at least VNC and QEMU Guest Agent socket. In other systems, at least you will need to update their path locations.